# Excel formula using today()

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Was wondering if anyone can help with this Excel formula I have hit a brick wall with.

I have a field which has dates in the following format

```
2018-07-02 11:37:19
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
```

In the adjacent column I have the following formula which displays a date and rounds the time off to the nearest 30 mins if it's today or adds some text if it's a historical day.

```
=IF(
    A2<=TODAY()-1,
    "16 Hours Failed",
    IF(
        A2<=TODAY(),
        "16 Hours Failed Yesterday",
        FLOOR(A2,0.5/24)
    )
)
```

Lastly I have another column (formula pasted below) which uses Col B to determine if its already failed, the already failed works fine. However none of the `TODAY()` functions work, I have a feeling this might have something to do with how Excel interprets `TODAY()`. Can anyone please assist?

```
=IF(
     B2="16 Hours Failed",
     "Failed Already",
     IF(
         B2="16 Hours Failed Yesterday",
         "Failed Yesterday",
         IF(
             B2=TODAY(),
             "Failing Today",
             IF(
                 B2=TODAY()+1,
                 "Failing Tomorrow",
                 IF(
                     B2>=TODAY()+2,
                     "Failing After 3 Or More Days",
                     INT(B2)
                 )
             )
         )
     )
 )
```

Comment: `IF(TODAY()>2018-07-02 11:37:19"` works okay for me. Excel interprets both as dates no problem. Can you show the sheet?

Comment: On a side note, these formulas make me shudder a bit. Using a bunch of nested `IF`'s is prone to errors and not easy to change the logic. You should use small lookup table instead, that way your formulas could be very small instead of using several nested `IF`'s.

Comment: Test to see if the date in A2 is a String or a Number.  If its a string you will need to convert it to an excel date first before using numerical or date operations.  `ISNUMBER(A2)` is a good starting point.  You want that to be true.  If its coming up FALSE, its because your date is actually a string and excel is having issues comparing it to the integer that comes out of TODAY().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FLOOR(A2, 0.5/24)` rounds down to the nearest half an hour.

`TODAY()` returns a date with the zero time component (midnight).

The two are only going to be equal for source dates with times from 00:00:00 to 00:30:00.

Apparently you want

```
IF(
    INT(B2) = TODAY(),
    ...
    IF(
        INT(B2) = TODAY()+1,
        ...
```

Comment: It seems the time is not relevant for the check he wants to do, so why not use DAY(TODAY()) in the checks?

Comment: @Chrisvdberge Apparently because then 10th of October will be equal to 10th of September.

Comment: ah yes of course.. you'd need the year() and month() then as well which doesn't make it any more convenient I guess